# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

I just updated my magento website from 2.3 to  2.4.3

Now I’m getting this error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'angolo.pagebuilder_template' doesn't exist, query was:
SELECT MAX(template_id) as max, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM (SELECT `pagebuilder_template`.`template_id`, `pagebuilder_te mplate`.`template` FROM `pagebuilder_template` WHERE (template IS NOT NULL) AND (template LIKE ('%data-content-type
="%')) AND (`pagebuilder_template`.`template_id` > 0) ORDER BY `pagebuilder_template`.`template_id` ASC
LIMIT 50000) AS `t`
[image]
Thanks
Fernando

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check into the database, the below table is exist or not :

> pagebuilder_template

And with this also confirm the data is there or not.

**How to get table** :

a. Install fresh magento and export `pagebuilder_template` from that one.

b. Now Import that file into your existing database.

Comment: I know that there is no table found. But how to add this table manually? May u help me?

Hi,

Is there someone who can help me add this table manually?

Unable to apply data patch Magento\PageBuilder\Setup\Patch\Data\UpgradePage  
  BuilderStripStyles for module Magento_PageBuilder. Original exception messa  
  ge: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'angoloja.pag  
  ebuilder_template' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT MAX(template_id) as max  
  , COUNT(*) as cnt FROM (SELECT `pagebuilder_template`.`template_id`, `pageb  
  uilder_template`.`template`

Comment: I update the answer, check how you get that table.